# How can I get and graphical monitoring for Processes, Memory using Shell script and php

Tags: php, shell

My project is using shell script to get RAM and CPU usage on linux.

How can I view these graphically with PHP?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be asking for external resources or for someone to tell you "how to write" this system. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what is considered [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague (hence all the downvotes).

It sounds like a) maybe you're on a Linux host, and b) maybe you want to use PHP to dynamically generate a web page.

SUGGESTIONS:

- Use /proc, vmstat and iostat to get performance statistics
- Use GD and gdchart to render your statistics graphically

Possibly helpful links:

- [Dynamically Creating Graphs and Charts with PHP and GDChart](http://devzone.zend.com/1281/dynamically-creating-graphs-and-charts-with-php-and-gdchart/)
- [8 commands to check cpu information on Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-cpu-information/)

Just pick *one aspect* of the problem (for example, "write a shell script to get current CPU utilization).  Get it working.  Then pick the next problem.  And so on.

Please post back with *new* questions about *specific* problems you encounter.